# Javascript array sorting issue between Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a large javascript array containing around 1000 student names. 
Each array element has the students ID number as its key, and the students name as its value.
It looks like this:

```
student_array['2312'] = 'Bloggs, Joe';
student_array['332'] = 'Carter, John';
student_array['9423'] = 'Davies, David';
```

and so on.

As you can see, the array is created in the order of array value. I then create a select box by iterating over the array, and creating an option for each value, where the array key is the option value, and the option value is the array value.

This is my javascript for creating the select box:

```
var student_select = '<select name="student_id" id="student_id">';

for(x in students_array)
{
    student_select += '<option ' + (student_id==x ? 'selected="selected"' : '') + ' value="' + x + '">' + students_array[x] + '</option>';
}

student_select += '</select>';
```

In internet explorer (8), this works fine, and the select box displays options sorted by the value.

In Chrome, it orders by the key. This is undesirable, as it makes searching for a name impossible.

**Question:**
How can I force chrome to order by array value?

Comment: Is it required that the array needs to be indexed by the student number? Can't you do it something like `var student_array = [[2312,'Bloggs, Joe'], [332, 'Carter, John'], [9423, 'Davies, David']];`?

Comment: That question hasn't been answered, and the best answer was updated in 2013. I'm looking for either alternative syntax or workarounds.

Comment: @Cerbrus It has to do with how the array, not with the dropdown list. The dropdown list is shown in the order it is in the source code, but since Chrome and IE handle the array in different ways you get a different result.

Comment: Note that there is a slight bug in the option creation, the value attribute it set to `x` instead of `student_id`, but i expect it's a copy-paste error.

Comment: @some: Oh, that's a good point, you're right.

Comment: In javascript strings are immutable (can't be changed) so first you have a string that is '<select name="student_id" id="student_id">', then '<select name="student_id" id="student_id"><option value="x">X</option>' then '<select name="student_id" id="student_id"><option value="x">X</option><option value="x">X</option>'... A lot of strings to be garbage collected and takes a lot of memory. You could create the dom-nodes in javascript. Use your favorite library or in plain javascript. Don't concatenate strings like it was still javascript 1.0 in the mid 1990's.

Comment: @some thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into it. I'm primarily a PHP developer (hence string concating), and if I use javascript, I use the jquery library, but for simplicity I used the string in this version. I'll look into optimizing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order in which elements are iterated over a for..in statement is undefined. IE happens to return them in the order they were added, while Chrome happens to make some optimizations regarding numeric-like keys, so it returns them in numeric order.

If order matters to you, you should use an array (and use it properly).

My suggestion:

```
var student_array = [
  { id : 2312, name : 'Bloggs, Joe' },
  { id : 332, name : 'Carter, John' },
  { id : 9423, name : 'Davies, David' }
];


var student_select = '<select name="student_id" id="student_id">';
for (var i=0; i<student_array.length; i++) {
    student_id = student_array[i].id;
    student_name = student_array[i].name;
    student_select += '<option ' + (student_id==x ? 'selected="selected"' : '') + ' value="' + student_id + '">' + student_name  + '</option>';
}

student_select += '</select>';
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/IXaCETEw/1/edit

Comment: My limited testing gives the same order in Chrome and Firefox (numeric order)

Comment: @some The jsbin seems to work well, "Bloggs, Carter, Davies".

Comment: Just tested it and works a charm :) Thanks very much. Thanks for the explanation as to why this behaviour happens as well, in addition to using your method, I tested prepending each key with 's' in order to force it to become a string which also worked. But I prefer your method.

Comment: @Tibos Your code works because you don't misuse the array :) Now, if you created an element with `document.createElement('select')` (or use a library) and added options to it instead of concatenating to a string.... that would be much better.

Comment: @some if it were CodeReview time, i would. I would also put var before student_id and student_name or just not use them alltogether. But it's not and i focused more on showing where the problem is and how to fix it than on improving the code.